# Is it possible to get the KEYVAULT URL from the list of scopes that I have added to bricks?

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-keyvault

I have a wide list of the keyvaults "mounted" to my databricks. I would like to verify which scope corresponds to which keyvault, as I was not the one who was adding those. How can I do it? Thanks for any advice, this is my first question ever ;)

I went through the Microsoft and Databricks documentation and found nothing helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways of getting this information:

- Use [List command of the Secrets REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/secrets#--list-secret-scopes) - for KeyVault-based secret scopes it will return KeyVault URL
- Use [Databricks CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/secrets-cli) to get this information:

```
databricks secrets list-scopes
Scope    Backend         KeyVault URL
-------  --------------  --------------------------------
test-kv  AZURE_KEYVAULT  https://test-kv.vault.azure.net/
```

Comment: Which of them have you used?

Comment: Databricks CLI works fine!

Comment: this command prints only Scope and Backend Type for me, Databricks CLI v0.212.1

Answer (score 0):

```
databricks secrets list-scopes -o json
```

https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/secrets/listscopes

```
{
  "scopes": [
    {
      "name": "string",
      "backend_type": "DATABRICKS",
      "keyvault_metadata": {
        "resource_id": "string",
        "dns_name": "string"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```